# Расшарить папку etc в windows 7

Tags: windows, windows-7

Требуется изменять/писать/читать файл hosts одного ПК в локальной сети с другого ПК в локальной сети. Открываю общий доступ папке etc, но с другого пк данная папка все равно не доступна "Разрешение на доступ ... отсутсует..". Возможно ли это в принципе ?

Answer (score 0):

Возможно.

1. Необходим доступ через административные шары;
2. Необходимы права администратора;
3. Расшаривать системные папки - моветон (это как постоянно работать
   под root - забудьте об этом навсегда).

Дополнение: зачем лезть в данный файл? Не проще ли правильно настроить Ваш dns-сервер?